# Create a new column using index in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a df with double indexation in python, where Asset and Scenario are the indexes obtained after using pandas.

```
As       Scen         V1     v2     v3
0           1         34     45     78 
0           2         30     95     58
0           3         14     -5     68
1           1         54     44     -8
1           2         34     45     78
1           3         39     40     96
2           1         34     45     68
2           2         94     -5     78
2           3         64     55     78
```

Additionally, I have two data frames with information related with the indexes.

```
Index   AssetName AssetExp
0       Asset1      X
1       Asset2      Y
2       Asset3      Z
```

```
Index   ScenarioName sensitivity
1       Scenario1       5
2       Scenario2       10
3       Scenario3       5
```

Using those data frames and the indexes how can i get the following data frame

```
  As       Scen             V1     v2     v3
Asset0    Scenario1         34     45     78 
Asset0    Scenario2         30     95     58
Asset0    Scenario3         14     -5     68
Asset1    Scenario1         54     44     -8
Asset1    Scenario2         34     45     78
Asset1    Scenario3         39     40     96
Asset2    Scenario1         34     45     68
Asset2    Scenario2         94     -5     78
Asset2    Scenario3         64     55     78
```

Comment: What have you tried before?

Answer (score -1):

Use pandas merge feature .

you can refer below articles

https://realpython.com/pandas-merge-join-and-concat/

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/join-the-dataframes-like-sql-tables-in-python-using-pandas/

Here is the code :

```
 df1 = {'As': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2},
 'Scen': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3},
 'V1': {0: 34, 1: 30, 2: 14, 3: 54, 4: 34, 5: 39, 6: 34, 7: 94, 8: 64},
 'V2': {0: 45, 1: 95, 2: -5, 3: 44, 4: 45, 5: 40, 6: 45, 7: -5, 8: 55},
 'V3': {0: 78, 1: 58, 2: 68, 3: -8, 4: 78, 5: 96, 6: 68, 7: 78, 8: 78}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)


df2 = {'Index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2},
 'AssetName': {0: 'Asset1', 1: 'Asset2', 2: 'Asset3'},
 'AssetExp': {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Z'}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)


df3 = {'Index': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
     'ScenarioName': {0: 'Scenario1', 1: 'Scenario2', 2: 'Scenario3'},
     'sensitivity': {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 5}}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)



df12 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='As', right_on='Index')


df123 = pd.merge(df12, df3, how='left', left_on='Scen', right_on='Index')[['AssetName','ScenarioName','V1', 'V2', 'V3',]]

df_final = df123.rename(columns={'AssetName':'As', 'ScenarioName':'Scen'})
```

Comment: When I run your code I have the following message ´TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'dict'> was passed´. QQ: are you considering 'As' and 'Index' as columns?

Comment: I just copied your code.  I mean your example, but is not reproducible.

Comment: I see, but as I mentioned before 'As', 'Scen', and 'Index' are not columns. They are indexes